# My JPGraph not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, include, require-once, jpgraph

I am using a jpgraph to generate a line graph in my wordpress. In my localhost, the line graph shows but when I uploaded my code in my live server, it seems like the included files for the jpgraph cannot be found.

I used the following code:

```
template-dashboard.php
<?php 
    include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/createjpline.php';
?>
<html>
<div>
    <?php GenerateLineGraph(); ?>
    <img src="lineGraph.jpg">
</div>
</html>



createjpline.php
<?php
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php';

function GenerateLineGraph() {    
    $datay1 = array(20,7,16,46,20,7,16,46,20,7,16,46);

    // Setup the graph
    $graph = new Graph(850,268);
    $graph->SetScale("textlin");

    $theme_class= new UniversalTheme;
    $graph->SetTheme($theme_class);

    $graph->title->Set($year);
    $graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,12);    

    $graph->yaxis->HideZeroLabel();
    $graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
    $graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
    $graph->xaxis->HideTicks(false,false);

    $graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'));
    $graph->ygrid->SetFill(false);

    $p1 = new LinePlot($datay1);
    $graph->Add($p1);

    $p1->SetColor("#5B9BD5");
    $p1->SetFillGradient('#61A9F3','#61A9F3');

    // Display the graph
    $graph->Stroke("lineGraph.jpg");
}

?>
```

The jpgraph folder and createjpline.php file are inside my theme-child folder. When I tried to comment out the required files in createjpline and echo a string in the GenerateLineGraph function, it echoes the string. However, when I place the required files, nothing shows. Please help! What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Hit F12 to open your web browser tools, reload the page and try the application again.  Does the console log show any errors?  Also, use the "network" tools, do you receive a 404 error for any of your required scripts?

Comment: Hi! Nothing is shown in the console log. I also checked the network tools, and there are no 404 error.